# Unlist a package from Nuget with all it's history versions

Tags: visual-studio-2010, nuget

I'm looking for a simple solution, on how to Unlist (delete) a package from Nuget library with all of it's versions.

I'm asking this, because manually I can do this 1 version at a time for 1 package. And I have lots of packages with ~20+ versions each ..

Please help.[image: Package History Listings]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could write a batch script to call `nuget delete`, iterating over all your packages - see http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/command-line-reference#Delete_Command

e.g.

`nuget delete MyPackage 1.1 -NoPrompt`

`nuget delete MyPackage 1.2 -NoPrompt`

etc. Pretty straightforward with grep or a search/replace in a text editor.

Comment: Thanx. I was kinda looking for a "more" automated solution :)

Answer (score 4):

I know this is old, but the nuget "delete" command is still not implemented, so I needed a solution. Perhaps someone can still benefit from this. I created a Command-line program and added the Nuget package Headless. Then, the code is:

```
 class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<PostEntry> parameters = new List<PostEntry>();
        using (var browser = new Browser())
        {
            var loginPage = browser.GoTo<LoginPage>();
            parameters.Clear();
            parameters.Add(new PostEntry("SignIn.UserNameOrEmail", "yournugetusername"));
            parameters.Add(new PostEntry("SignIn.Password", "yournugetpassword"));
            parameters.Add(new PostEntry("ReturnUrl", "/"));
            parameters.Add(new PostEntry("LinkingAccount", "false"));
            parameters.Add(new PostEntry("__RequestVerificationToken", loginPage.Find<HtmlElement>().ById("signIn").Find<HtmlInput>().ByName("__RequestVerificationToken").Value));

            browser.PostTo(parameters, new Uri("https://www.nuget.org/users/account/SignIn"));
            Console.WriteLine("logged in");


            var cont = true;
            while (cont)
            {
                var packagesPage = browser.GoTo<PackagesPage>();
                Console.WriteLine("at packages page");

                var links = packagesPage.Find<HtmlElement>()
                    .ById("published")
                    .Find<HtmlLink>()
                    .AllByPredicate(o => o.GetAttribute("title") == "Delete"
                        && (o.Href.Contains("/IdOfPackageIWantToDelete/")
                            || o.Href.Contains("/IdOfAnotherPackageIWantToDelete/")));

                cont = links.Count() >= 1;
                if (links.Any())
                {
                    var htmlLink = links.First();
                    var linkPage = htmlLink.Href;
                    Console.WriteLine(linkPage);
                    var deletePackagePage = htmlLink.Click();

                    parameters.Clear();
                    parameters.Add(new PostEntry("Listed", "false"));
                    parameters.Add(new PostEntry("__RequestVerificationToken", deletePackagePage.Find<HtmlElement>().ById("body").Find<HtmlInput>().ByName("__RequestVerificationToken").Value));

                    browser.PostTo(parameters, new Uri("https://www.nuget.org" + linkPage));
                    Console.WriteLine("delete submitted");
                }
            }

        }
        Console.WriteLine("Hit any key to quit");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
    public class LoginPage : HtmlPage
    {

        public override Uri TargetLocation
        {
            get { return new Uri("https://www.nuget.org/users/account/LogOn?returnUrl=%2F"); }
        }
    }
    public class PackagesPage : HtmlPage
    {
        public override Uri TargetLocation
        {
            get { return new Uri("https://www.nuget.org/account/Packages"); }
        }
    }
}
```

It will take a little while to run, but it does the trick.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with PowerShell, here is a function:

```
function Remove-AllNuGetPackageVersions($PackageId, $ApiKey)
{
    $lower = $PackageId.ToLowerInvariant();

    $json = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/$lower/index.json" | ConvertFrom-Json

    foreach($version in $json.versions)
    {
      Write-Host "Unlisting $PackageId, Ver $version"
      Invoke-Expression "nuget delete $PackageId $version $ApiKey -source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json -NonInteractive"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are hosting your own nuget gallery, you could execute the following SQL query against the nuget database:

```
select 'nuget delete ' + pr.Id + ' ' + p.Version + ' {ApiKey} -source {Source} -noninteractive' from Packages p
join PackageRegistrations pr
   on p.PackageRegistrationKey = pr.[Key]
where pr.Id = '{PackageId}' AND
   p.Listed = 1
```

Replace {ApiKey}, {Source} and {PackageId} with your own values, I then placed the results in a batch file adjacent to nuget.exe and executed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of tools by creating a simple console application.

Create a new Console application and install the package "Nuget.Core".

Add the following method to get a list of all package versions:

```
private static IEnumerable<IPackage> GetListedPackages(string packageID)
{
    var repo = PackageRepositoryFactory.Default.CreateRepository("https://packages.nuget.org/api/v2");
    var packages = from package in repo.FindPackagesById(packageID)
        where package.IsListed()
        select package;
    return packages;
}
```

Then copy `nuget.exe` from the ".nuget" folder in one of your projects into the console application project (add it in the solution explorer and make sure that it's copied to the output directory)

[image]

Next create a new method which uses `nuget.exe` to unlist the package version:

```
private static string UnlistPackage(IPackage package, string apiKey)
{
    var arguments = $"delete {package.Id} {package.Version} -ApiKey {apiKey} -NonInteractive";
    var psi = new ProcessStartInfo("nuget.exe", arguments)
    {
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        WorkingDirectory = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory,
        UseShellExecute = false
    };
    var process = Process.Start(psi);
    process.WaitForExit();
    return process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Finally change Main method so it gets a list and removes all versions:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var packageID = "yourPackageName";
    var apiKey = "yourKeyFromNugetOrg";
    var packages = GetListedPackages(packageID);
    foreach (var package in packages)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Unlisting package " + package);
        var output = UnlistPackage(package, apiKey);
        Console.WriteLine(output);
    }
    Console.Write("Completed. Press ENTER to quit.");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

source: http://blog.gauffin.org/2016/09/how-to-remove-a-package-from-nuget-org/